# How to create interactive animation with Swift Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to create an animation where you touch and drag your finger across the screen and colored boxes change size based on your position. Imagine this as a color picker. Here's a gif of the idea. I did this in Corona using a touch event and enterFrame. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to create the same effect in Cocoa Touch.

Where to start with this? I can't seem to find an enterFrame equivalent in Cocoa Touch unless I go with SpriteKit. I'm not making a game, so SpriteKit seems like overkill.

[image: Sample interactive animation]

Comment: Sprite kit could do it but I feel it's not really necessary. It sounds like you need to measure the distance between your finger and each of the squares positions in touchesmoved. Then use those distances to change the size of each square using some kinda math.  That's the way you'd approach it using sprite kit as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree, sprite kit seemed not right in this case. I have the math worked out. Fitting into the Cocoa Touch framework is where I'm having trouble. The example I posted is programmed in Lua, it uses an enterFrame event to update the size and position of the boxes. I can't find an equivalent in Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a simple animation code on github : https://github.com/MehdiSv/SimpleAnimationColorsPicker

I used a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, and made a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` depending on the **distance** between the **touch** and **each view**.

Here is a little *preview* :

[image: Preview]